# Firefox is not centering table, despite using margin: 0 auto

Tags: html, css

The following HTML fails to create a centred table in FireFox, even though it works in Chrome and IE. I've tried using margin: 0 auto and that doesn't help. Can anyone help me?

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ICG Administrator Login</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
h1 {
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    color: #00377E;
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
table {
    -webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
    -webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #053F89;
    color: #444;
    display: table-cell;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    position: static;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Gateway and CDUE Administration</h1>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: #053F89; background-origin: padding-box;"></div>
<DIV style="text-align: center;">
    <form method="GET" action="j_security_check">
    <BR>
        <table>
            <tr style="background-color: #053F89; font-weight: bold; color: white;">
                <td colspan=2>Log In</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="j_username" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="j_password" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form></DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's [the HTML and CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfQWA/) on jsFiddle.net.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of line 42, `display: table-cell;`

Comment: Thanks for your very concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `display:table-cell` on the `table` element. That's incorrect. Remove it, and your problem gets better.

P.S. *In the future, you should try fully paring down your problem to a minimal test case. Delete code—HTML and CSS—that is irrelevant. The `h1`, the `font-family` CSS, etc. The process of doing so will show you the problem ≈80% of the time; the rest of the time it leaves you with a simpler problem that will easily get you help.*

*Deleting code until it got better is how I found your problem.* :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try that in the future.

Answer (score -1):

It's because your HTML document lacks `<!DOCTYPE type='html' />` directive. Put this line at top of your document, and it's done :)

Also a recommendation: Try to use shorthand syntax whenever possible to make your CSS file more manageable. For example, instead of

```
padding-top: 50px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
```

use:

```
padding: 50px 30px 3px 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind for the future.